# Java Byte as repeating counter best practice

Tags: java, byte

I want to use a var of type byte to implement a counter which counts from 0 to 255 and starts again by 0.
What's the best method to increment a byte just by 1, is it possible to do it without type casting? Is there a method which resets 0xff to 0x00 automatically when adding +1 ?

Comment: I think you'd better use C/C++ for this!

Comment: please give the reasosn you use byte instead of Integer for this

Comment: Remember that the `byte` type in Java is signed - it represents -128 to +127, not 0 to 255.

Comment: it's kind of homework where we need to implement it as byte... if I could decide this by my own, I would use C as mentioned ;)

Comment: I found a way to display the binary representation of bytes and it seems to be that a simple ++ operator does exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

```
int myCounter = 255;

//increment
myCounter = (myCounter+1) % 256;

//or even faster hack
myCounter = (myCounter+1) & 0xFF;
```

also note that if you for any reason need to increment very often and very fast, and then occasionaly read, you can increment without moduling / masking, and modulo / mask the counter at the time you read its value

Comment: is there a possibility to do that using var type byte without casting?

Comment: Well, in that case, i really dont know about anything alse than use C/C++ instead